# Finding Password

Tags: javascript

Here is the question:

```
wrongPassword([["John", "J"], ["Mike", "Y"], ["Ion", "F"]], {"John": "J", "Mike": "C", //"Ion":"I"})
```

Comment: Well, you haven't given your function a name, so how do you call it?

Comment: "Should return me ["Dick", "Harry"]" Where are those names coming from? They aren't referenced anywhere else in your post.

Comment: "but it's wrong". How is it wrong? What is it returning? Please include a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: You are comparing 2 arrays, which can't be done by default in JS

Comment: why should it return `"Ion"`? Attempt for Ion is `["Ion", "F"]` but credentials are `"Ion":"I"`. Shouldn't it only return `"John"`?

Comment: Run it in a browser and check the console.

Comment: hello101, do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://<sitename>.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 1):

So, you're trying to use an object as an array and directly compare array to object as values.

What you need to do is use the object as an object, and compare the values within these, for this I suggest the following code;

```js
function wrongPassword(attempts, credentials) {
  // Create your array
  let duplicate = [];
  // Loop the object, getting the key-value pairs
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(credentials)) {
    // Walk your array
    for (var i = 0; i < attempts.length; i++) {
      // Get the name and password from the attempt(s)
      name = attempts[i][0];
      password = attempts[i][1];
      // If the name matches the object key and the password doesn't match...
      if (name == key && password != value) {
        // Push this to the duplicate array
        duplicate.push(attempts[i]);
      }
    }
  }

  return duplicate;
}

// Do your thing!
console.log(wrongPassword([
  ["John", "J"],
  ["Mike", "Y"],
  ["Ion", "F"]
], {
  "John": "J",
  "Mike": "C",
  "Ion": "I"
}));
```

This does do what you asked, but there are better ways to do this, for example, if someone doesn't exist at all (e.g. `["Dave": "davina"]` these won't be displayed in the duplicates)

I have only done the basic here, up to you to make it better!

Comment: pasting it here, `Array.filter()` version: `return attempts.filter(attempt => credentials[attempt[0]] !== attempt[1]).map(result => result[0])`